# Can eclipse debugger follow newly spawned thread

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

In a multi-threaded application, if I set a break point on the thread that spawns another, is it possible, when stepping through, to get the debugger to jump straight to this new thread after the `start()` method, rather than the line after `start()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the code for the thread and breakpoint the first line then hit run. That's the only way I know of to do it.

Comment: Yeah that's how I've been doing it.  Just curious in case there was a way of just following on.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As far as I know the Eclipse debugger works with threads separately, meaning once you stop on a breakpoint it follows that thread, once the flow moves to another thread if you do not have a breakpoint in the code where the new thread went, it will not switch over and instead will continue with whatever the original thread has to do.

Comment: That's how pretty much every debugger works really. It has to as otherwise you would be jumping around every time the thread context changed.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys, was just curious if there was an additional setting or something.